# Debian 8.5 - Service : command not found

Tags: mongodb, service, zsh

I've installed MongoDB following this (https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/?_ga=2.104926336.2025310627.1509020418-427799538.1509020418) but when trying to start MongoDB with : `sudo service mongod start` , i get a error indicating `zsh: command not found: service`

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know your operating system.  You may be on something
modern enough to support Systemd.  In that case, the appropriate
command is something close to:

```
% sudo systemctl start mongodb
```

That works on an Arch Linux system.  Yours might be called `mongod` or
something similar.  You can just type the `mongo` part of it and hope
that Zsh will complete it appropriately.